# Support for Managed Code Rule Sets in Rider

Tags: c#, rider

I'm currently working on a project where we use a set of managed code rule sets using a .ruleset file, and have not been able to find a way to get it to work in Rider - am I missing something, or does Rider not have support for custom code rule sets?

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't confirm it works, but I think you can add a ruleset to your `.csproj` file in a configuration, like this:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x64'">
  <OutputPath>bin\x64\Debug\</OutputPath>
  <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>..\path\to\myrules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
  <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
</PropertyGroup>
```